# Is there any way to 'peek' a value from a Resources file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Most of the text in our application's UI is stored in Resources (.resx) files, in a separate project to the UI code itself. It's frustrating that if I see `@HomePageResources.MainTitle` or some such in my page's markup, the only way to see what text will actually be displayed after compiling is to either start debugging and load the page (even more frustrating that you can't then edit the value in the Resources file without ending debugging again), or navigate to the Resources file and then find the value manually, which, given the size of our solution, takes more than a moment.

It seems like the most obvious thing in the world that I should be able to hover my cursor over the reference to the Resources file value in the markup to see its value, or at the very least be able to right-click on it and select an option akin to Peek Definition to see the value, but as far as I can tell there is no such option.

Is there any easy way to view a value in a Resources file from references to it in code that I'm missing? Or a VS extension which would add this functionality (I've looked but can't find one)?

Answer (score 1):

[String Resource Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.StringResourceVisualizer) extension shows the text of a string resource (.resx) when used inline in code.